# Htaccess redirect from one page to another?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all traffic from a url to another url (all on the same domain).
So it would go like `/my-page` would redirect to `/our-page`. And the most important thing is that i don't want to use absolute url, as this .htaccess file (and urls) will be on several different domains (dev, test, etc) so the redirect needs to work on of 'em.

Comment: OK, sounds like a great plan. But what is your question? You did not post your current attempt or implementation, so we cannot really help without you explaining what it is you cannot get right yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer i was looking for if anyone else stumbles with this

`Redirect 301 /page1 /page2`

Where page1 is the page you are redirecting from (and page2 is the being redirected to). Worked like a charm